# Interpreting JSON code for MySQL database schema

Tags: python

I'm completely new to JSON and would like to understand how to interpret the following code. Basically, I asked my database to provide me with DB schema and this is what he gave me. I understand SQL and want to create a visual representation of schema of it. Can someone please simplify it.

````
class Vendor(models.Model):
    AUTH_CHOICES = tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable([(
        ('KEY', 'KEY'),
        ('PASSWORD', 'PASSWORD'),
        ('CUSTOM', 'CUSTOM'),
    )]))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_index=True, unique=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    authentication_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=AUTH_CHOICES, default='KEY')
    authentication_inputs = jsonfield.JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default={},
                                                dump_kwargs={'cls': JSONEncoder, 'indent': None,
                                                             'separators': (',', ':')})
    tags = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    in_house = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature, related_name='vendor_features', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    has_multiple_keys = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.label or self.name
class VendorApi(models.Model):
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='apis')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_index=True, unique=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    plugin = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.label or self.name
class VendorApiField(models.Model):
    GROUP_CHOICES = tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable([(
        ('COMPANY', 'COMPANY'),
        ('PERSON', 'PERSON'),
    )]))
    TYPE_CHOICES = tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable([(
        ('STRING', 'STRING'),
        ('INTEGER', 'INTEGER'),
        ('FLOAT', 'FLOAT'),
        ('CURRENCY', 'CURRENCY'),
        ('DATETIME', 'DATETIME'),
        ('OBJECT', 'OBJECT'),
        ('ARRAY', 'ARRAY'),
        ('URL', 'URL'),
    )]))
    vendor_api = models.ForeignKey('VendorApi', related_name='fields', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True, unique=False)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='STRING')
    example = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    rl_api_field = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=GROUP_CHOICES, default='COMPANY')
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('vendor_api', 'name', 'rl_api_field') ```
````

Comment: Provided code is neither SQL nor JSON. Please clarify...

Comment: @Akina You may be right, but I dont know what to do. What do you think I should do/ask to my team?

Comment: This code looks like a code on some programming language which uses some framework. Define them firstly.

Comment: this seems more like some kind of python code. In terms of asking your team: why don't you simply ask them what they gave you and how to use it? It is better to admit you do not understand something upfront - they will realise that anyway soon.

Comment: My firm uses Django as front and MySQL as backend. I asked the data guy to provide me with the current schema and this is what was provided. @Shadow

Comment: Then this is the django model (django is written in python). for the database. Set a django project up (there are tons of tutorials out there to get you started and asking us to recommend one is explicitly off topic here on SO) and get it run your model. Or ask your contact to provide you with an sql database schema.

Comment: @RaviBhagwat How would you like to visualise the data? From what i know these are django models.

Comment: @SaGaR Well to have visual representation of the schema like how we can create in MySQL workbench

Comment: @Ravi I don't know much about sql but i know django. If you can share a example maybe i can help

Comment: Basically, an entity relationship diagram. which displays how the tables are connected and what kind the relationship they have. What is the primary key, foreign key. @SaGaR

Comment: @Shadow Thank you for the suggestion. I will ask that.

Comment: If you want a visualisation of the db strcuture, ask one of the developers to generate it for you using mysql workbench.

Comment: Since you're using Django, something like [django-extensions](https://medium.com/@yathomasi1/1-using-django-extensions-to-visualize-the-database-diagram-in-django-application-c5fa7e710e16) might be what they could use to visualize their existing model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i can understand from Owners comment and questions. What you need is just to understand how the models are connected. Let me explain it to you.

```
1.) Vendor is a Model which is connected to another model named feature via foreign key relation(i.e one to many relationship)
2.) Vendor Api connects to Vendor Model via the same foreign key relation as above.
3.) Vendor ApiField connects to VendorApi model via foreign key relation.

To summarise:
Feature <-- Vendor <-- VendorApi <-- VendorApiField
```

Where <-- shows the relationship via foreign key. (i.e. one to many relationship)in sql

Comment: Appreciate it a lot.